# How to connect Samsung Tab 2 10.1 to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, mount, android

I have this Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 tablet and when connecting it to my system through USB I get this error message:

> Unable to mount GT-P5113
>   Error initializing camera: -53: Could not claim the USB device

I have USB debugging enabled and when disabled I get the same error message. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look on the setting of the device itself. I had a similar issue with my Galaxy Player and after beating my head against the wall for 2 hours, I started looking at the device. In Settings/Wifi and Bluetooth/USB, changed from Media Player to Mass Storage. This worked for me, your mileage may very.